# How to carry a phone stylus in winter without losing it

Tags: storage, phone, travel

I bought a stylus for playing Pokemon Go outside in the winter, when it's too cold to use my hands. I've been just keeping it in my coat pocket, the same as my gloves, but it keeps falling out. I haven't lost it yet, but it's going to happen some day unless I find a better solution.

More info/limitations:

- The stylus I have is about 5-6 inches (same height as my phone)
- My phone has an otterbox case on it
- My stylus has a clip on the end, like a mechanical pencil
- My coat only has the two regular pockets, no breast/inside pocket, and no zippers on the pockets

So how can I store my stylus securely & portably, and prevent myself losing it?

Comment: Does your phone have a case?

Comment: @Snow: Yes. Updated the question with that info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a case...

Take the phone out of the case and wrap a rubber band around the case, most of the way toward the top.

Then put the phone back in the case, trapping the rubber band behind it.

You then have a taut rubber strap on the back of the case that you can clip your stylus onto.

When you're not chasing Pokemon, just take the rubber band off the case.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to attach your stylus to the glove, when wearing them?

That is, attach the stylus to the backhand side of the glove so that it doesn't disturb your hand movement. This should work as long as the stylus isn't too long compared to the back of your hand.